# Fetching particular link (without <a> tag)

Tags: regex

I am working on detecting links from the strings and format them in a way that a browser can understand.

Here is my string:

`https://www.google.com <a href="https://www.youtube.ca" target="_blank">RBC Connect</a>`

From the above string, I only want to fetch `https://www.google.com`, not `<a href="https://www.youtube.ca" target="_blank">RBC Connect</a>` tag

Comment: Assuming all your text strings appear with the same format, you'd just locate the first `<` then copy everything that apeared before it. Simples. If this is unsuitable, it's because your suite of examples (size 1) is too small and they do not have the same format, contrary to your claims.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression bounded with two `"`, would capture our desired URL:

```
"(https?[^\s]+)"
```

using this capturing group: `(https?[^\s]+)`.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/VlsxfM/1/)

If we like to not capture the `"`, non-capturing groups might work:

```
(?:.+")(https?[^\s]+)(?:".+)
(?:")(https?[^\s]+)(?:")
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/BdQKse/1/)

Or with positive lookaheads, if that'd be OK:

```
(?=.+")(https?[^\s]+)(?=".+)
(?=")(https?[^\s]+)(?=")
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/daQxBF/1/)

Comment: Is there any way, to fetch the only link without " and "